# Clues to prove average in T is minor or equal than average in a smaller inner interval.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Suppose I want to prove (or disprove) this assertion

Let $f$ be a discrete function, $T,h,k$ are constants

So these terms are averages over $T$ and over $h$

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{T}\frac {f(i)}{T}$ $\leq$ $\sum\limits_{i=k}^{h+k}\frac {f(i)}{h}$

$h+k$ $\leq$ $T$

If there is an obvious theorem about this or similar would be great!, if not... where can I start?

Comment: There are $T+1$ terms in the LHS and $h+1$ in the RHS.  Is that intentional?

Comment: I don't think your assertion is correct. What if the values of $f$ not contained in the average on the right,e.g. $f(0)$ or $f(T)$ are much larger than the other values?

Comment: @WimC good comment,  thanks, fixed (I think)

Comment: @user69810 added "or disprove", the thing is how to elaborate this kind of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T=4$, $k=1$, and $h=2$. Define $f$ by $f(0)=f(T) = 100$ and $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 0$.

Then $$\Sigma_{i=0}^{T}\frac{f(i)}{T}= \frac{100}{4} + \frac{100}4{} = 50$$

$$\Sigma_{i=k}^{h+k}\frac{f(i)}{h}=0$$

Therefore, your assertion is false.